# how to execute certain tasks in intervals(task schedular)

Tags: java

I have some type of task for example in a loop with same method but different arguments,
I need to execute these tasks in one after another in some intervals,
and all this activity need to be execute in again and again in a particular schedule,
e.g. let say I have a method called

```
public void GetData(String tablename){
}
```

so first time I will provide table1 then table2 then table3.....
similar to for loop but need some interval in between,

and same above all execution need to execute in each 10 min,

sample code I have implemented as

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() { 
                      getData(String table);
                      }
                };
                final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle =
                  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 1, 10, SECONDS);
```

its working fine for one table for need help and best way to implement for multiple tables.

Comment: " all execution need to execute in each 10 min," and "scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 1, 10, SECONDS);" Doesn't tie up?

Answer (score 0):

tryjava.util.Timer to schedule a task to execute

```
        public class ReminderBeep {
              Toolkit toolkit;

              Timer timer;

              public ReminderBeep(int seconds) {
                toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
              }

              class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
                public void run() {
                  System.out.println("Time's up!");
          toolkit.beep();
          //timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
          System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
            }
          }

          public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
        new ReminderBeep(5);
        System.out.println("Task scheduled.");
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Thread.sleep() in your loop (if it's not on the main thread). Something like this (the code is not tested so may contain errors):

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         getData(String table);
     }
     Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```